# Merging uncommitted changes into some other branch using SVN

Tags: svn

I have copied `/trunk/project_a` to `/branches/project_a/test_1`. However, I have not yet committed the newly created branch. Then I did some changes in the working copy which I originally intended to commit with the newly created branch. However, after I was done, it seems better to commit those changes into the trunk. (I could then commit the branch without the changes and merge them from the trunk or I just revert the branch creation and branch anew. That doesn't really matter.)

***My question***: Is there a way to merge uncommitted changes (and from an uncommitted branch) in SVN?

Comment: How did you manage to get a working copy of a branch that you haven't committed yet? If you did an actual "svn cp", it has surely created the branch in the repository. If you did not do "svn cp", what do you mean by "I have copied"?

Comment: You can create a branch on your disk first, that's then scheduled for addition (see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create). This is what I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in your case it's easiest to just commit everything where it is and merge back to trunk.
But if you're really desperate you could try to create a patch file, apply it to trunk and revert your changes in the branch.

Comment: In the end, I went the patch file approach. Too bad, I thought SVN would provide a way to extract and merge uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to switch your working copy to the other branch and then commit the changes.

As far as I know, there is no way to merge uncommitted changes. svn wants you to specify a range of revisions to merge so that it can compute the diff to apply, and you can't do that without committing the changes first.

Comment: But I cannot switch an uncommitted branch, can I?